# jQuery Validate multiple extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using https://github.com/DiegoLopesLima/Validate this validation plugin to validate the form

I added extensions and I want to use 2 extension rule in one field

Something like this

```
'data-validate' => ' max , min ', // in field
```

---

```
jQuery.validateExtend({
        min: {
            conditional: function(value) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        max: {
            conditional: function(value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is example how use in one rule I want multiple rules

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="age" data-validate="age" />
</form>

jQuery('form').validate();

jQuery.validateExtend({
    age : {
        required : true,
        pattern : /^[0-9]+$/,
        conditional : function(value) {

            return Number(value) > 17;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not exactly be the answer you are looking for but this can be done in pure HTML. The drawback is that it requires a modern browser (IE10, Chrome, Firefox etc.) to be used. The advantage is that its much easier to use and works without JS.

Check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Specifcally for what you need, go here and look at the "How old are you" input example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Other_validation_constraints

```
<input type="number" min="12" max="120" step="1" id="n1" name="age" pattern="\d+">
```

Looking at your code you are looking for a required age input where the value must be greater than 17, this would be for example:

```
<input type="number" min="18" id="age" name="age" pattern="\d+" required>
```

Hopefully this helps a little.

Comment: You should be able to use HTML validation for whatever you need. Why exactly do you need to use jQuery to validate your form over HTML?

Comment: My question is about this plugin, I don't want to discuss about my digressions...

Comment: Very well, just saying that there really isn't any need for using jQuery validation anymore over HTML.

Comment: Again, min and max is just samples... I want for example check if number is float what is your suggestion how check input value in html ?

Comment: <input type="number" step="any" id="number" name="number" pattern="\d+" required>

So keep the type as number and set step to any, this allows decimals.